# Finding the $x$-intercept when variable has fractional exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation is $$2x-3x^{\frac 23}+4 = 0$$ 
How would one go about finding the x-intercept(s) of this equation?

I have tried, but am unable to isolate the $x$.

EDIT: Changed from g(x) = expression to expression = 0. My mistake.
Also, the fraction is 2/3, not 3/2

Comment: Just solve the equation

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution $u=x^{1/3}$, or $x=u^3$. The equation then becomes

$$2u^3-3u^2+4=0$$

Try to factor the polynomial on the left hand side. If that fails (which it does here), use the usual methods for solving a [cubic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function). Warning: this is messy, but it works.

**UPDATE:** [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2u%5E3-3u%5E2%2B4%3D0) gives the answer
$$x^{1/3}=\frac 12 \left(1-\frac 1{\sqrt[3]{7-4\sqrt{3}}}-\sqrt[3]{7-4\sqrt{3}} \right) \approx -0.91082$$
This makes $x \approx 0.75561$.

I was too lazy to work it out myself, but it can be done. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2x%5E3-3x%5E%282%2F3%29%2B4%3D0) chokes on the original equation and gives only numerical answers. I guess taking the cube of that expression is too difficult.

Comment: Rory, Rob changed the equation to $2x - 3x^{\frac{2}{3}} + 4 = 0$, so you now want $u = x^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Yes, I saw that and changed my answer just before I saw your comment.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean the equation $$2x-3x^{3/2}+4=0$$? If so then we have $$\frac{2x+4}{3}=x^{3/2}$$ squaring this we get $$\left(\frac{2x+4}{3}\right)^2=x^3$$ and this is equivalent to 
$$-{x}^{3}+4/9\,{x}^{2}+{\frac {16\,x}{9}}+{\frac {16}{9}}=0$$
one solution is $$x \approx 1.886423789$$

Comment: It would be better perhaps to add why we are making the RHS equal to 0.From what I can see,that's what the OP is having trouble understanding.

Comment: You may not have noticed that the OP changed the equation after you posted your answer. You may want to modify your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

make a change of variable $u = x^{1/3}$ so that you can work with positive integer exponents. with that change of variable, your equation reads $2u^3 - 3u^2 + 4 = 0.$
solve this cubic equation for $u.$  use $x = u^3$ to get the solution for your equation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this myself. Here's the process:
Start by making a graph using the following method
1. Find the y-intercept. When x = 0, y = 4
2. Take the 1st derivative of the equation and find the critical points.
Then find in which intervals the graph is increasing and decreasing
3. Take the 2nd derivative and find the concavity of the function.
4. Take the critical points and plug them into the original equation to get max and mins
5. Make a rough graph from this information. You'll see only one x-intercept exists and it
occurs when x < 0.
6. Use Newton's Method. Start by choosing a point that is less than 0. I chose -3.
Newton's Method is used to approximate the roots (x-intercepts) of a function.
7. The root is -0.755610167
8. I plugged the equation into a graphing calculator, and it said the root was -0.756, so the estimate is good

Basically, when the original equation was manipulated, I came up with a cubic equation. Since cubic equations are very difficult to solve, I had to try to approximate the root instead. Newton's Method does just that, but you have to know where to start. Steps 1-5 uses Calculus methods to help make a graph. Once a rough graph was made, I can see roughly where the x-intercept occurs. Knowing that, I chose an arbitrary point around the vicinity where I think the x-intercept may be and plugged that into Newton's Method equation. This method is quite tedious, but it took 2 calculations I believe to reach the x-intercept.
This wasn't exactly thorough, but with a little research into curve sketching with derivatives and Newton's Method, you can get the same answer.